# Too few arguments inheritance c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm working on learning inheritance by making a generic `List` class. `List` can be an `Unordered` list, an `Ordered` list, a `Stack`, or a `Queue`.

My `List` class looks like this:

```
class List
{
public:

    class Node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node(int data);
    };

    int sizeOfList = 0;
    Node * head = nullptr;
    List::List();
    virtual void get(int pos);
    virtual void insert(int data);
    virtual void remove(int pos);
    virtual void list();
    virtual int size();
};
```

My `Unordered` list class looks like this:

```
class UnOrderedList : public List
{
public:
    UnOrderedList();

    void get();
    void insert(int data);
    virtual void remove(); //takes no parameters because first item is always removed
};
```

In `main()`, I create an array of Lists like this;

```
List * lists[8];
```

and make an Unordered list like this:

```
lists[0] = new UnOrderedList();
```

**My question:**
`lists[listNum]->get();` gives error

> "too few arguments in function call"

because it thinks I am trying to call `get()` in the `List`class, but I want it to call the Unordered list's function `get()`.

Comment: Because how does it know that `lists[0]` points to an UnOrderedList, not a SomeOtherRandomList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel I must improve upon Sam Varshachik's answer - though he is totally correct.

```
class List
{
public:
    virtual void get(int pos);
};
class UnOrderedList : public List
{
public:
    void get();
};
```

Note that there are two problems here - not just one.

Firstly the signature of `get(int)` is different from `get()` - these are **two different methods**, and the compiler will treat them as such.
Further you have declared that the method `List::get(int)` be virtual, but you have not done-so for `UnOrderedList::get()` - Remember that the `list` object has *no knowledge about it's children* - Thus a `list *` cannot understand the details of `UnOrderedList`.

Consider this example:

```
class List
{
public:
    virtual void get(int pos);
};
class UnOrderedList : public List
{
public:
    virtual void get(); //STILL AN ERROR!
};
```

In this case, I have made `UnOrderedList::get()` virtual - However this won't help. As **list still has no knowledge of this method**.

The correct snippet is as follows:

```
class List
{
public:
    virtual void get(int pos);
    virtual void get();
};
class UnOrderedList : public List
{
public:
    virtual void get(); //We can use this now!
    virtual void get(int pos); //This is only needed if we intend to override this method
};
```

In this example `list::get()` is now a virtual method - as such any call to it will be communicated to the correct-child as you intended.
This is only possible however because *the parent class has been informed that such a method exists, and can be over-ridden by the child classes*.

## [edit /]

As JonathanPotter stated in the comments, pay attention to the fact that the *virtual* keyword is only needed if you wish for a method called from a parent-pointer to be routed to the actual child object. And that this does incur some overhead.

Comment: Note that the methods in `UnOrderedList` don't need to be declared as `virtual` unless you want to be able to override them in a class that inherits from `UnOrderedList`.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't appear to match what Jonathan was saying.

Answer (score 2):

You need declare `get()` as a virtual method in the `List` class. Either that, or `dynamic_cast` it.

When you invoke `get()` using a pointer to a `List`, that particular pointer can point to any subclass of `List`. Just because one particular subclass of `List` implements a particular method doesn't mean that you can invoke it directly using a pointer to the base class.

Otherwise, there's no point to have base classes. And this is exactly what virtual methods are for: to allow you to invoke the methods in a subclass, using a pointer to the base class.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at the wrong thing, but aren't I declaring get() as a virtual method in List class already?

Comment: Do I need to declare get(int) virtually as well?

Comment: You are declaring get(int) as a virtual method. You did not declare get() as a virtual method. get(int) and get() are two completely different methods.

Answer (score 1):

`lists[0]` is a `List*` as far as the compiler's concerned.

`UnOrderedList::get()` won't override `List::get(int pos)` because the signatures are different. If you want the derived class to override a function in the base class the function signatures have to be the same.

As it is, you would need to cast `lists[listNum]` to `UnOrderedList*` to call `UnOrderedList::get()`, e.g. `static_cast<UnOrderedList*>(lists[listNum])->get()`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I am trying to use listNum to access the type of subclass, and avoid casting. Is my thinking irrational? is there some way to avoid casting with 4 different if() casting statements?

Comment: @TysiaKrepps I don't think you do understand. `UnOrderedList::get()` does not override the function in the base class because it doesn't take the `int pos` argument that `List::get()` takes.